Interesting vanishing identities of Gaussian integrals
Recently, I came across some interesting vanishing identities involving Gaussian integrals. I have checked them for up to six variables, but I have no idea how to prove them (except for the trivial cases where the power of the middle homogenous polynomial is odd).
I conjecture that for any $1\leq  k < l \leq N$ the following integral is zero:
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}a_{1}\cdots
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}a_{N}
\exp\left(-a_{1}^{2} - a_{2}^{2} \cdots-a_{N}^{2}\right)\ \times
\\ & \left[\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N-1} (a_i - a_j)^2\right]\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{k}\left(a_{N} - a_{i}\right)\right]\left[\prod_{j = l}^{N - 1}\left(a_{N} - a_{j}\right)^{2}\right]  = 0
\end{align}
For example, consider a simple case k =2, l = N. Is it possible to show that
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty da_1 \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty da_N e^{-a_1^2-a_2^2-\cdots-a_N^2} \left[\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N-1} (a_i - a_j)^2\right](a_N - a_1)(a_N - a_2)$
is zero for all $N\geq 3$? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

There are many ways to compute gaussian integrals, but basically you face an expression of the form $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{-x^TAx}p(x) \,\mathrm{d}^Nx$, where $p(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(x)$ is a polynomial expression with
$$
\begin{array}{l}
   \displaystyle
   f_1(x) = \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N-1} (x_i-x_j)^2 \\
   \displaystyle
   f_2(x) = \prod_{i=1}^k (x_{N}-x_{i}) \\
   \displaystyle
   f_3(x) = \prod_{j=l}^{N-1} (x_{N}-x_{j})^2
\end{array}
$$
In the present case, one has $A = I_N$, that is why the variable $x$ can be interpreted as a $N$-dimensional gaussian distribution whose components $x_i$ are iid. In consequence, ony the totally even-powered terms in $p(x)$ will contribute to the integral; in other words, a term $x_1^{n_1} \cdots x_N^{n_N}$ with at least one odd exponent $n_i$ will vanish through integration. Thus, we need to count the even-powered terms produced by the product of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$.
As you have noticed already, if $k$ is odd, then there is no totally even-powered terms and the integral always vanishes. Let's assume that $k$ is odd from now on. Apart from the squared terms, there is no common "mixed  term" in $f_2$ and $f_3$, because $x_ix_N \in f_2$ and $x_jx_N \in f_3$ respectively, but $i \le k < l \le j$. Consequently, one has $f_3(x) \equiv x_l^2 + \cdots + x_N^2$, where the equivalent sign means that the other terms in $f_3$ won't contribute to the integral. Thus, $f_3$ can't affect the final result, up to scaling.
Next, given that $x_N$ doesn't appear in $f_1$, the non-vanishing terms produced by the product of $f_1$ and $f_2$ will be due to either squares in $f_1$ which don't appear in $f_2$ if $k < N-1$ (but they will have the same effect as those in $f_3$), or terms like
$$
(x_i-x_j)^2(x_N-x_i)(x_N-x_j) \equiv (x_i^2+x_j^2)x_N^2 - 2x_i^2x_j^2 \equiv 0.
$$
So, everything vanishes at the end.

Thank you very much for your answer! But I'm confused by two things: 1. In the second to last paragraph, $f_3(x)$ has power depending on $N$ and $l$, so why it is always equivalent to a quadratic form? 2. It seems to me that we can't simply throw away cross terms in $f_2(x)$ or $f_3(x)$, because $f_1(x)$ can also produce cross terms. For example take $N = 5$ in the last paragraph. $-x_1^3 x_2 x_3^2 $ from $f_1(x)$ and $x_1 x_2$ from $f_2(x)$ combine to be a totally even-powered term right?

@HNAO  As already said, $f_3$ will bring an odd power of $x_N$ which cannot be completed by a mixed term of $f_2$, because $i < j$. And some mixed terms of $f_2$ will be associated to those of $f_1$, but their (negative) contributions are balanced by the squares, in such a way that the final result vanishes. Perhaps I'm mistaken somewhere in my reasoning, but I let you carry the exhaustive analysis at the end.

After playing with some examples, I'm afraid that it is perhaps more subtle. But still,  your answer is useful and thank you for your help!
